# How to modify state in reduxjs/toolkit with React and TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

When i worked with react-redux i updated the state like this:

```
case CartActionTypes.ADD_ITEM:
  return {
    ...state,
   cartItems: [...cartItems, { action.payload }];
  };
```

Now i'm using reduxjs/toolkit with slices, etc.

Should i update the state in the same way or maybe using .push method like this:

```
export const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'cart',
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: {
    addItemToCart(state, action) {
      state.cartItems.push(action.payload);
    },
}
```

Should i always return the state like i did usin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Mutating and Returning State](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers#mutating-and-returning-state) doc

> Immer expects that you will either mutate the existing state, or construct a new state value yourself and return it, but not both in the same function! For example, both of these are valid reducers with Immer:

```js
const todosSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'todos',
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
    todoAdded(state, action) {
      // "Mutate" the existing state, no return value needed
      state.push(action.payload)
    },
    todoDeleted(state, action.payload) {
      // Construct a new result array immutably and return it
      return state.filter(todo => todo.id !== action.payload)
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

State becomes "mutable" when you are defining reducers inside RTK `createSlice`. You can therefore use `push` to update your state without returning it.